Android - Workmanager is not working as expected
Hello dear Stackoverflow community
following code in my app behaves not as expected :-(
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements

and running this code in onCreate()
private void initPeriodicLog(){
        FileLogger.debug("Worker", "24 hour logging is enabled!");
        // Creating a periodic WorkRequest
        PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest =
                new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                        .build();
        OneTimeWorkRequest dailyWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class)
                //.setInitialDelay(24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                .build();
        //Places WorkRequest in the WorkManager queue
        WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(periodicWorkRequest);
    }

My Worker class:
public class MyWorker extends Worker {

    private static final String TAG = "OMSWorker";
    private MyApplication appContext;

    public OMSWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
        appContext = (MyApplication)context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
       

        try {
            ErrorReportUtil.sendErrorReport(appContext);
        } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException | ConfigurationException | ZipException e) {
            FileLogger.error(TAG, "ErrorReport has crashed!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // delete temporarily created files
            ErrorReportUtil.deleteCreatedFileFromErrorReport();
        }
        FileLogger.debug(TAG, "24 hour report was sent successfully!");
        return Result.success();
    }
}

I would expect the work manager with the test settings to send something to the server every hour of the day and within that hour in a 15 minute time window. Unfortunately, I only receive an error report(ErrorReportUtil.sendErrorReport()) sometimes every 1 hour. Tonight the period between 12 p.m. and 3 a.m. was not covered at all. Sometimes the Workamanger sends an error report twice within a few minutes.
I was also playing around with OneTimeWorkRequest
My actual goal is to run this worker exactly once per day. So seven times a week and so on.
What am I doing wrong?
